# Como criar eventos em C#?

Tags: c#, eventos

Tenho duas classes uma que tem uma lista e gostava de ter um evento que toda a vez que essa lista fosse alterada esse evento fosse chamado.

```
public class Exemplo
{
    List<string> lista = new List<string>();
    //Quando esta lista foi alterada
}

public class Exemplo1
{
    protected virtual void QuandoListaAlterada(EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Lista Foi Alterada");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma das formas é extender a classe List adicionando um evento, desta forma:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace teste
    {
        class Program
        {

            class ListaComEventos<T> : List<T>
            {

                public event EventHandler OnAdicionar;

                public void Adicionar(T item)
                {
                    if (OnAdicionar != null)//verifica se evento foi especificado
                    {
                        OnAdicionar(this, null);
                    }
                    base.Add(item);
                }

            }

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                ListaComEventos<int> minhaLista = new ListaComEventos<int>();
                minhaLista.OnAdicionar += new EventHandler(EventoAdicionar);
                minhaLista.Adicionar(1);
                minhaLista.Adicionar(1);
                minhaLista.Adicionar(1);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            static void EventoAdicionar(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Um elemento foi adicionado");
            }
        }
    }
```

Aqui está o código rodando no [.netFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hnrF7h)

Comment: Mas e se essa lista nao estiver declarado no main ?

Comment: Isso foi só um exemplo. Você pode declarar onde voce quiser, desde que a referência seja válida.

Answer (score 5):

## Explicação

Existe um tipo de collection no C# que notifica as alterações realizadas na lista através de eventos, a [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx).

Com ela, você poderá atribuir um método no evento `CollectionChanged` para receber as notificações de alteração na lista e também utilizar o evento `PropertyChanged` para receber notificações de alterações nas propriedades.

## Exemplo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace ObservableCollectionExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ObservableCollection<string> list = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            list.CollectionChanged += List_CollectionChanged;

            list.Add("Teste 1");
            list.Add("Teste 2");
        }

        private static void List_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A lista foi alterada.");
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>Veja funcionando no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0LjhU6)</sub>